# Casting in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, casting, nsstring

I have a dictionary object that I am pulling data out of. The field is supposed to be a string field but sometime all that it contains is a number. I get the info using:

```
NSString *post = [[temp objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"POSTDESCRIPTION"];
```

So it is going into a string object. However, when I try to assign that to a cell's text via:

```
cell.textLabel.text = post;
```

I get a the following error:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSDecimalNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4106a80'
2009-10-20 13:33:46.563
```

I have tried casting it with the following ways to no avail:

```
NSString *post = [[[temp objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"POSTDESCRIPTION"] stringValue];
NSString *post = (NSString *)[[temp objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"POSTDESCRIPTION"];
cell.textLabel.text = [post stringValue];
cell.textLabel.text = (NSSting *)post;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you're pulling a NSDecimalNumber instead of a string. Are you sure you're not converting before storing the value in the NSDictionary?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your dictionary doesn't contain an `NSString`. If you'd like the string representation of the object, you could call the object's `description` selector, e.g.:

```
NSString *post = [[[temp objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"POSTDESCRIPTION"] description];
```

Comment: In other words: There is no such thing as casting objects in Objective-C.

Comment: There certainly is casting of objects in Objective-C. You just can't cast an object to something that it's not. And and NSNumber is not an NNSString.

Comment: @Terry: No, what I said was correct. You can't cast an object in Objective-C. You can cast *pointers* from one type to another, but that doesn't typecast the object being pointed to.

Comment: @Chuck: Ah, I see what you're saying. The thought of expecting casting to change the underlying object never occurred to me.

Answer (score 0):

terry, jason and the other answers & comments are correct.  what you're attempting would be like trying to cast an apple into an orange.

conveniently, NSNumber does have a stringValue method.  so try this:

```
NSString *post = [[[temp objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"POSTDESCRIPTION"] stringValue];
```

only do this if you know for sure it'll always be an NSNumber.

otherwise, you can try the rather hacky and inelligant:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[temp objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"POSTDESCRIPTION"] description];
```

Comment: There is no point at all to the `NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",...` in your last example. Just calling `description` gives you a string, and using a `%@` specifier in `stringWithFormat:` calls `description` on that argument, which in the case of an NSString just returns `self`.

Comment: true, i got overzealous, [[temp objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"POSTDESCRIPTION"] would've sufficed.